# How I can create a batch file to silent install an MSI program without 1 component?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-installer

How can one create a batch file to silently install an MSI program without 1 component?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know what all the component options are, you can do the following:

```
msiexec /i [msi filename] /qb COMPADDLOCAL=LIST,OF,COMPONENTS,TO,INSTALL
```

The annoying thing about this method is that you have to find our the names for each and every component that you want to have installed, rather than just the one component you want to *not* install. This is doable, but can be a pain. You can use [`Orca.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to help find out what all of the component and feature IDs are.

See [KB230781](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230781) for more info.

Comment: Thanks lots nhinkle, this means that I'll have to list all my components to where you wrote COMPONENTS, and separate them one by one by comma?

Comment: @JPEmedi that is correct.